# accessibility aria-live reading order changes on ios

Tags: html, ios, accessibility, wai-aria, aria-live

I am trying to add accessibility to a dynamic page and I have a div to where all the content gets replaced and its marked as polite for aria-live.

```
<div id="replace-content" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="additions"></div>
```

When the content gets replaced everything get read as expected, but when I replace for the content

```
<p id="p1"> A Title </p>
<p id="p2"> Some text </p>
<table id="table">
a Table with multiple rows and 2 columns
</table>
<p id="p3">  More Text </p>
```

ios VoiceOver reads in the order p1, p2, p3, table intead of p1, p2, table, p3.

This only happens on ios VoiceOver using chrome's ChromeVox works as expected.

Does anyone know how to change the reading order in ios?

Comment: I am seeing a similar issue. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Out of curiosity, I tried inserting the content in the order I wanted it read using setTimeout. As expected, this did not work well. iOS VoiceOver reads the entire content again when new content is added, even if `aria-relevant="additions"` is set.

Comment: Additionally, setting `aria-live` on each child element sequentially with a `setTimeout` delay does not work; VoiceOver only reads on the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not happy with the workaround, but you can apply `aria-live` to each child element at the time that the child is added to the DOM, and iOS VoiceOver will read it in the proper order. However, this results in MacOS VoiceOver not reading the content at all. Hmm.